# Tool to convert pdf files to SWF

Tags: pdf, flash

Is there any open source tool to convert PDF to SWF other than pdf2swf tools?

Comment: I take it you have a PDF that won't convert properly with pdf2swf?

Comment: Yes, i have a pdf where the images are oval in shape and when i create SWF out of it using pdf2swf the images are rectangle in shape

Answer (score 2):

pdf2swf uses "xpdf" to process PDF files.

You can try ImageMagic, it uses a different library (gscript) to process PDF files. You will have to convert to some intermediate format (like JPG/ SVG) and use a different tool to create SWF.

Comment: Try increasing DPI of the intermediate images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SWFTOOLS? On Debian/Unbuntu:

sudo apt-get install swftools
pdf2swf filename.pdf
http://wiki.swftools.org/index.php/Examples#pdf2swf They have a Windows version, and the source so you can compile it on other Linux flavors